# How can I send data from javascript to swift?

Tags: javascript, swift

I am doing an iOS hybrid app using swift and HTML/Javascript. IN Android I can use web view:

```
 WebSettings settings = web view.getSettings();
 settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"Book");
webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/test.html");
```

public void back() {
....
}

and in test.html there is a javascript when you click a button you run javascript code: Book.back(); so the control will go from javascript to android to run the function back(). How can I do something similar in swift ?

```
import WebKit
....
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "html")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
```

Comment: You are supposed to use `WKScriptMessageHandler` to pass the message from Javascript to Swift , on catching specific message you can take a corresponding action. Like send message with CTA as string in it or something like that. Logic you need to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Make use of below code. Here the below code keeps looking for message from javascript and specifically for "paymentHandler"

```
import WebKit

class PaymentGateWayViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate,WKScriptMessageHandler{

var containerView = UIView()
var webView: WKWebView?


override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    containerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    contentController.add(self,name: "paymentHandler")
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.containerView.bounds,configuration: config)
    self.view = self.webView!
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "paymentHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")

}

}
```